# Can I save a Google Sheet as an older XLS, rather than a XLSX file?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-apps-script-api

I want to achieve this with Google Apps Script, or the Google Drive API directly.

I know it is possible to create a new XLSX file from a Google Sheet

```
var url = file.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL]; // xlsx
```

but I have an older application that requires a XLS file export. I also know I can convert it using MS Office or various third-party tools but I would like to do it in one step.

Using the older

```
var url = file.exportLinks['application/vnd.ms-excel'];
```

url is undefined but not error, so I assume it is simply telling me it is unsupported.

I also tried this directly in the address bar, note the "xls" rather than "xlsx":

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xls&id=[MY_FILE_ID]
```

But it said it can't open that file.

Comment: Have you tried exporting the file to xlsx, and then simply changing the file name from xlsx to xls?

Comment: I think that in the current stage, Google Spreadsheet cannot be converted to `application/vnd.ms-excel` while `application/vnd.ms-excel` can be converted to Google Spreadsheet with Drive API. You can see about the export mimeTypes at ["Method: about.get"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/about/get?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22exportFormats%22%7D). When you want to convert Google Spreadsheet to XLS, I guess that the outer API might be required to be used. At that time, XLXS can be converted to XLS. If this was not your expected comment, I apologize.

Comment: XLS is no longer supported as per this [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-export-formats) of exported MIME types for Google Workspace documents.